# How to handle new line character in FB-api via twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I am currently working on symfony2 framework. In one of my twig file

```html
FB.api(
    "/" + p_id + "/feed",
    "POST",
    {
    "message": "{{ des| replace({"\n":' ', "\r":' '}) }}",
    "description": "{{ des| replace({"\n":' ', "\r":' '}) }}",
    "access_token": p_accessToken
    },
     function (response) {  
        if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
        console.log("posting");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
        else {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
           alert(response.error.error_user_msg);
          }
       }
      );
```

I want to replace "\n" such that facebook treat this as a new line character.

If I leave as it is than it render something like this:

"message": "first line

So, it gives error and not considering second line.

How to resolve this problem??

Comment: You can use `{{ des|nl2br }}` to convert the new lines to `<br />`'s.

Comment: Sorry! that doesn't work for me. It shows "line 1 &lt;br /&gt; line2" on FB post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh!!

Error resolved!!

```html
FB.api(
    "/" + p_id + "/feed",
    "POST",
    {
    "message": "{{ des| replace({"\n":"\\n", "\r":"\\n"}) }}",
    "description": "{{ des| replace({"\n":"\\n", "\r":"\\n"}) }}",
    "access_token": p_accessToken
    },
     function (response) {  
        if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
        console.log("posting");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
        else {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
           alert(response.error.error_user_msg);
          }
       }
      );
```